# Python IDLE, Module Docs and Python(command line) can not pop out

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just installed python 2.7.10. Then, when I tried to open IDLE(Python GUI), Module Docs and Python(command line). I can only see "please wait while windows configures python 2.7.10". IDLE(Python GUI), Module Docs and Python(command line) never pops out.

Then, I opened a command window under C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib and entered "python idle.py". I got a following error:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib>python idle.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "idle.py", line 11, in <module>
    idlelib.PyShell.main()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1541, in main
    root = Tk(className="Idle")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1814, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive,     want
objects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    {C:\Python27\tcl\tcl8.5} C:/Python27/lib/tcl8.5 C:/lib/tcl8.5     C:/lib/tcl8.5
C:/library C:/library C:/tcl8.5.2/library C:/tcl8.5.2/library

C:/Python27/tcl/tcl8.5/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have     8.5.2,
 need exactly 8.5.15
version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.2, need exactly 8.5.15
    while executing
"package require -exact Tcl 8.5.15"
    (file "C:/Python27/tcl/tcl8.5/init.tcl" line 19)
    invoked from within
"source C:/Python27/tcl/tcl8.5/init.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source $tclfile]"


This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

What should I do in order to pop up IDLE(Python GUI), Module Docs and Python(command line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer's in your error; the easiest way is probably just reinstall it.

Comment: I reinstall it for several times. It never shows up. But if I enter python on command line, it can work.

Answer (score 0):

So Tcl is a packages for GUIs. Basically it allows the computer to create popup windows. Since IDLE relies on a pop-up window, the lack of Tcl will cause it to crash. Now for Windows (which is what I am assuming you are using), there is free [ActiveTCL](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl) by ActiveState. Here is the link for that app.

There is also a [video](https://youtu.be/NB3N1g2FvCw) for the install of this package. Trying installing it and then re-running idle. If that does not work, then try reinstalling python and running 'pip install tkinter' to install the python interface to Tcl. The run idle again after doing these steps.

Comment: I still got the same error message. Do you know what is the version of TCL and TK? Should I change 'package require -exact Tcl 8.5.15' to 'package require -exact Tcl (current version)'

Comment: did you try to install tkinter before running IDLE again? Also, check if there are windows updates after installing activetcl. It might be that some dll file has to be updated based upon the newly installed software.